# Анализ трафика приложения для Android

Tags: android, wifi

Здравствуйте.

Мне хотелось бы перехватить интернет-трафик от приложения под Android. Хочется узнать заголовки, содержимое запросов и куда все это отправляется. Все, что нашел в play маркете, либо выдает не то, что нужно, либо не работает. Есть ли способ перехватить запросы?

Comment: прокси сервер, например

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@metalurgus](/users/3997/metalurgus) прав, нужен прокси. Если хотите немного облегчить(?) себе задачу, то на вашем аппарате должны быть root-привелегии.

Из маркета ставьте [SandroProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy), нажимаете на вторую кнопочку и сворачиваете программу. Далее отсылайте необходимые запросы, затем снова откройте SandroProxy (там, кстати, есть веб-морда - можно зайти с ПК и смотреть запросы он-лайн), нажмите на "паузу" и "обновление". Всё, пакеты готовы для анализа.

Если есть 2 устройства и они подключены к одной Wifi-сети, то на второе устройство можно установить Wi.Cap PRO (ищите на 4пда) и перехватывать абсолютно весь вайфай-трафик там.

Comment: вообще есть способ сделать прокси и без рут прав. Я писал полгода назад такую библиотеку (да простит меня всевышний) для очень направленной рекламы. Но секрет ее, к сожалению, выдать не могу, мне за нее хорошо заплатили, и их коммерческую тайну я выдать не могу...

Comment: @metalurgus,

>вообще есть способ сделать прокси и без рут прав

Я тоже об этом думал, пока додумался поднимать VPN на локалхосте и перехватывать пакеты на девайсе-отправителе.

>для очень направленной рекламы

Если это сервис iMarker, то я лично готов придушить заказчика/гендиректора этой конторы :) У айМаркера сложилась тенденция к перехвату данных, у них даже договор с моим провайдером на это есть...

Comment: @SuperCreeper, я не знаю названия, просто разработал им СДК... Но думаю, что это не аймейкер. VPN поднимать слишком палевно, ибо все время висит нотификейшен, и требуется единоразовое подтверждение от пользователя.